# Download css files from web page

Tags: download, css, webpage

How can I download css files from webpage which are

> @import /css/main.css
>   @import  /css/style.css

and so on.
 
Actually I have to  download all the webpage, which is made using php. And **there is only one text file where @import is written.** 
I used **WebHttrack** But it downloads only html files. I have to download all files including css files which are used using **@import** tag.

Comment: You can download the Webdeveloper toolbar for Firefox. Then you can view the CSS (including the imports). It will display everything for you so you can take a copy. Not a perfect answer, but if you're desperate then it will suffice despite being laborious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8-10 press F12, select CSS tabs, press save.

CSS save as 1200 code page.

Internet Explorer 8:

[image: Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools CSS save]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [file2hd.com](http://file2hd.com/) or (google search 'file2hd Unblocked') That works for most websites unless the creator has set up specific headers or security measures to prevent such access. I use it alot for learning other peoples code. if this fails use firefox developer edition click on the menu icon then 'save page as' > complete website, within the folder that has been saved you should be able to view or locate the css file. Another alternative would be to use the developer tools click on the body, navigate to computed styles and just copy them manually (Although this would probably be a long and tedious task). Hope one of these helps.

Another Alternative to File2hd that you could try is:
[robin-goods: Website Dowloader](http://tools.robingood.com/1361210/download-any-website-in-full-including-code-css-and-assets-website-downloader)

!Sorry That one only links to an article about it, heres the actual App: [websitedownloader.io](https://websitedownloader.io/)

You can also view this answer for more refference: [Download css, js , images of website](https://superuser.com/questions/1391825/download-css-js-images-of-website-as-mentioned-in-view-page-source?rq=1)