# Download css, js , images of website as mentioned in view page source

Tags: wget, css

I downloaded source code of  [this page](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150)
using below command :

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p  https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150
```

**Issue** :

but it downloaded all css, js, imags in one file....

**Requirement** :

but i need to download all the css, js files separately as mentioned in  view page source

**Note**: using above link for learning purpose, not for commercial use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use mirror option. Try the following:

`wget -mkEpnp -e robots=off https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150`

It should create a recursive offline copy, updating urls, adding extensions to extensionless urls etc.

Comment: Thanks , I tried your command , but it gave only one file , i need all files separately as like `Httrack`....

Comment: Ah, the page includes `NOFOLLOW` directives - you need to add `-e robots=off` to you arguments.